# As a customer, how to deal with an unresponsive company representative without poisoning the relationship?

Tags: verbal-communication, written-interaction

I am currently in the process of building a house, which is quite a stressful experience.

The site administrator (my immediate contact person) was recently replaced.  The previous administrator was a great communicator, giving me a call once a week to let me know the status of the build.

The current site administrator is the complete opposite.  I have to always chase him down, via text message, phone call or email.  Often he doesn't respond at all, and when he does he says he will message me later that day and then doesn't follow through.  This has happened consistently for the past month.

I am going to have a business relationship with him going forward (at least until the house is built) so I don't want to create any awkwardness with him but at the same time I'm not getting what I want.  I can't see a suitable way for how to approach this without basically calling him incompetent and therefore souring the relationship.

Any recommendations about how to handle this situation?

Comment: Is there anything (e.g. a contract, or a marketing leaflet or whatever) that states that as a customer, you'll be getting weekly updates? Why do you think telling the current administrator what you told this site (previous one updated once a week, I appreciated that, would like to get that from you too) will make him think you're calling him incompetent?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - no, nothing in the contract regarding communication.  I'm going to try the direct approach and see how it goes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't see a suitable way for how to approach this without basically calling him incompetent and therefore souring the relationship.

Well, calling him incompetent won't help (apart from making you feel better for a short time), so you can skip that idea.

It's not you, it's him: He's either overworked or does not care, and nothing you can say to him will fix that. In my personal experience, you have two options to deal with this problem:

1. Accept the unpleasant situation and keep bugging him weekly until you get the information you need.
2. Escalate: You cannot change his behavior, but his manager might. Talk to someone higher up in the food chain of the company building your house and explain your situation. Don't vaguely complain about the guy ("He's unresponsive", etc.), but be clear about what you want (e.g. "I'd like a call once a week about the status of the build"). It's not guaranteed to work, but, contrary to you, they at least have the leverage to make him comply.

Answer (score 0):

In these situations, I try to give the other person the benefit of the doubt and I let them know it. This minimizes putting them in a defensive position, which would probably make them even less likely to reply or help.

For example, when following up, you can say something like:

> "I know you must be busy, I appreciate your help with this. Were you able to get an update on X?"

You can also approach it with curiosity regarding and bring up the change in communication with something like:

> "X and I worked together like this. How do you prefer to work together?"